# Loading driver from two views in different methods. Starting with CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my first question on StackOverflow. I'm starting with my first development in codeigniter and I have a question with the views. In my controller I load the view in the index function, but I want to load another from a method in the same controller. How do I do it? Need another controller to the resend method?

```
public function index($_msg = NULL)
    {
        $data['title'] = 'The title';
        $data['msg'] = $_msg;

        $this->load->view(DIRECTORIO_ADMIN . '/login_view2', $data);

    }

public function procesar(){
    {
        //some code here

    }

public function reenviar_password(){
    {
        $this->load->view(DIRECTORIO_ADMIN . '/resend_password_view');

    }
```

Comment: are you wanting to load the view that is in the reenviar_password() method?

Comment: the controller is of a login process. I have a link to retrieve the password, so you load a different page where it asks the user for the email and the whole process is done in the method reenviar_password. To load that view, what must I do? Actually this is my purpose.

Comment: I don't understand @tereško revision, I would explain that one. As I'm starting with IC and am very interested to know why you do that revision.

Comment: Because the question is unrelated to MVC design pattern. You are asking about how to modify the default framework behavior. It is about CodeIgniter's implementation details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments I get to know that you want to show login view using index method, and forgot password view when user clicks on "forgot password" link and it is on Login view

For doing this you have to do like this: Create a login page and add a url for "Forgot password" and add a forgot password functions url to it so that when user click on "Forgot password" they will get redirect to http://example.com/index.php/controller/reenviar_password

Comment: Correct. That's what I do. Doubt comes when loading the view that contains the password resend form, which is a view with a complete document with all html tags. If I load the resend view in the new method, what about the view login_view2 being loaded in the index() of the same controller?

Comment: You have to use single function at a time, when you use login method do everything in it, like showing row view, validation, re show form fields, check this example for showing view http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#thecontroller

Comment: I understand. But imagine something as simple as a wordpress login. The login form view the load in the index () and everything you need to login (validations, etc.) in login (). If I want to retrieve the password, within the same controller, I go to another method. In that case how I hold the view of the new page if you used the index ()? The only thing I can think of is that you can put a URL to check if the arriving and load a view or another in each case.

I get the feeling that my question is pretty basic, but I am stuck at this point and I see no way to continue doing it the best way.

Comment: OK. It occurred to me something very simple addition. Is it right? one method to load the view (only) and one method to validatios and so all. This last is the one who is the form action url in the view. It is right?